# Android gradle file to remove unused resources

Tags: android, optimization, build.gradle, android-lint

I would like to remove unused resources from my final release apk file created. I am able to configure proguard but its limited to Java files only. I would like to remove unused layouts, strings, pngs etc Any ideas?

I read android link can help; got the script here: http://yltechblog.blogspot.in/2012/06/remove-unused-resource-from-android.html but i donnot know how to integrate it with gradle.

Similarly: https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/; claims to help; but i am unable to figure out how to integrate it with gradle.

My gradle file is as follows

```
// COMMANDS::
// gradle --build-file adt_build.gradle clean  build 
// adb -e install  -r build/apk/rpsl-debug-unaligned.apk

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' } 
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

def artifactoryurl='http://10.10.8.10:8081/artifactory'
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' } 
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "$artifactoryurl/jfrog-libs"}
    maven {url "$artifactoryurl/plugins-release"}
    maven {url "$artifactoryurl/libs-local"}    
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4' , 'android:support:v4', 'wavecrest.mobile.libraries:libraries:2'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    signingConfigs {
        debugconfig {
            storeFile file("../configs/keystore.jks")
            storePassword "asdf"
            keyAlias "rpsl"
            keyPassword "asdf"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugconfig
            zipAlign true
            runProguard true
            proguardFile file('configs/proguard-android.txt')
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debugconfig
            zipAlign true
            runProguard true
            proguardFile 'configs/proguard-android-optimize.txt'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest{
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lint support is not complete yet with the android gradle plugin. It is scheduled for [next release](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/roadmap).

From there, you might be able to use the lint results. In gradle to execute a script do something like 'script'.execute()

Comment: As a build tool i was expecting gradle to give hooks by which we can execute our custom scripts/ commands just before jar building/ signing/ packaging things...

Comment: There are some hooks, but not as fine grained to the best of my knowledge.